# RAILS || ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Error on new model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model which belongs_to Pay model. So when a user is created, its (years) attribute is used to query the Pay model and return an object which contains a rate. Everything works if I query via:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pay
end

* CONTROLLER ACTIONS *
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.pay = Pay.find(1)
=> #< Pay object returned with attributes....>
```

But the following returns a ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ....... which is an instance of Pay::ActiveRecord_Relation

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.pay = Pay.where("years = ?", @user.years) #FAILS
```

Also tried the following....

```
@user.pay = Pay.where(years: @user.years)
@user.pay = Pay.where(years: params[:years]
```

And even inputing a string....

```
@user.pay = Pay.where(years: "3")
```

So the query is returning an instance of ActiveRecord_Relation instead of an AssociationType??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` always returns an ActiveRecord relation, `find` returns a single instance. You can use `where` like this for similar effect

```
@user.pay = Pay.where(years: @user.years).first
```

however a better way would be

```
@user.pay = Pay.find_by(years: @user.years)
```

Comment: Thanks Iceman. I was darn close as I tried to append .limit(1) which still failed. Your solution works and I've learned a little more about ActiveRecord. Cheers mate!

Comment: FWIW `.limit(1)` still returns a _one_ ActiveRecord relation which is can be thought of as an array not an ActiveRecord.